# Where is the folder 'assets\internal\' in Android?

Tags: android, delphi

If I deploy my files to assets\internal, where is it in Android phone?

I opened up Explorer and look at the phone's contents, can only find something
like : Internal shared storage\Android\data\com.embarcadero.project1\

but when I click on 'cache' or 'files' subfolders, both are empty.

Please advise where to find my deployed file.

Comment: Internal files are private to your Android application, they are not accessible to Explorer.

Comment: 1) Is there a folder (read/write) I can use if I want the file to be visible?   2) Is there another folder to use (read/write) if I don't want the file to be deleted when App is uninstalled (for purpose of being able to use back the old settings when App is re-installed)

Comment: You can use the documents directory which is visible. You can determine the path by System.ioutils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath. I don't know if you can deploy to that directory, but you can copy the files there yourself at the first start.

Comment: I'm actually already using system.ioutils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath which is actually saving my file to a folder, which I cannot find this original file.